# Changing the angle of attack of a double element wing

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm trying to change the AoA of my double element wing but I'm not sure about how I should do it in a proper way. Here are the details of the geometry;[image][image]

Main plane AoA: 3.45 deg
Flap AoA: 22.39 deg
Combined Wing AoA (Chord of the combined wing is a line which connects the leading edge of the main plane with the trailing edge of the flap) : 14.59 deg
Overlap: 9.12 mm
Gap:  12.13 mm

The combined wing AoA is mentioned in the literature but I wasn't able to use this value to evaluate the AoA of my wing because there are lots of main plane AoA and flap AoA combinations which can give the same value of combined wing AoA. Overlap and gap can also be used as degrees of freedom to complete the geometrical definition of a front wing but I don't quite like this idea.

I have another idea to define the geometry of the front wing and this set of parameters should define where the main plane and flap are on the endplate, as well as their positions relative to each other. My parameters would be;

1-Main plane AoA
2-Flap AoA
3-x-y coordinate of the main plane center of pressure (assuming it is c/4 from leading edge) taking a point on the endplate as origin. Since I am rotating the main plane about the center of pressure to increase the AoA, I used that point.
4-x-y coordinate of the flap center of pressure (assuming it is c/4 from leading edge) taking a point on the endplate as origin. Since I am rotating the flap about the center of pressure, I used that point.

So one question still remains. What is truly meant by the AoA of a front wing and how do you change the AoA of a front wing considering those definitions I mentioned?

Best Regards,
Metin

Comment: AoA typically refers to the overall angle applied after all the elements have been rigged with their individual translations & rotations.

Comment: @D.Halsey Then what should I do to change this overall angle? Should I rotate those elements about their quarter-chord points individually or should I rotate all elements together about the quarter chord point of the main element? Or maybe I should rotate all elements together about the quarter-chord of the combined wing? I failed with rotating the elements individually about their corresponding quarter-chord points because those elements coincide with each other after the rotation (increasing the AoA of flap and main plane for instance) which shouldn't be the case in my opinion.

Comment: Would not [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) be a better forum for this question?

Comment: Do not rotate the elements individually. That will change the gaps & overhangs. You can rotate the entire airfoil about any point that's convenient (unless there are other components in the flow) or in free air, you can rotate the freestream direction instead.